# Changing Password of Generic User for multiple servers

Tags: shell, unix, sas

I need to change passwords for a generic user of multiple unix servers in one go. The problem is I need to login with my user id and then switch to generic user and only then I can change the password for that particular server and I need to repeat the same for all the servers. Is there any unix script which can help me out or is there any SAS code to do the same? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

[chpasswd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/chpasswd.8.html) seems to be what you are looking for, use it just right from within a shell script:

```
<log in to server X>
echo <user>:<new password> | chpasswd
<adjust file permissions - see caveeats in link provided>
<log out>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate.. My requirement is like: Suppose there are 5 servers(S1, S2,S3,S4,S5). I login to S1 with my user id and password. Then I use the 'su - ' to switch the user. Then I enter the password for the same user. Only then, I can change the password and I have to do it for all 5 servers.

Comment: So you manage to do it for one server? Such as ssh root@S1 "command1;command2;command3"?